# Nested search parameters in URL query

Tags: json, http, url, search, url-parameters

I have a JS object literal structure for nested search parameters that looks something like this:

```
var search = {
    op: 'and',
    cri: [
        {f: 'foo', o: '=', v: 123},
        {
            op: 'or',
            cri: [
                {f: 'bar', o: '<', 456},
                {f: 'baz', o: '>', 789}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

The equivalent `WHERE` clause for a SQL query for that structure would be:

```
(foo = 123 AND (bar < 456 OR baz > 789))
```

This structure allows me to model nested search criteria well, but I'm not sure what the best practice is for passing advanced data structures like this via an HTTP `GET` request.  If it were a `POST` request, I would just JSON-encode and stick it in the message body with the appropriate `Content-Type`.  However, this is a search, so semantically, I should be using HTTP `GET`.  As I see it, my options are:

1. JSON/URL-encode the structure and pass it as one URL query parameter and let the server decode it
2. Come up with a really awkward DSL that translates this structure into simple key/value pairs (somehow)
3. Use built-in array syntax for URL query parameters (e.g. `?search[0][op]=and&search[0][cri][0][f]=foo&...`)

Are there any options better than these?  If not, which is the "best" of the three?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` was specifically designed for data transfer. Use option 1 and deserialize it on the server. Simple and easy.

Comment: Im also interested in hearing what is the best way of handling this scenario